# Exception handling of subprogram calling subprogram

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method which has a subprogram which is again calling a subprogram. The last subprogram can throw an exception. Who is responsible for catching the exception? Or who is able to catch the exception?

So are the exceptions passed up in the calling stack until a method catches them? Or is only the calling method responsible for catching the exception of the subprogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3

Each program should handle its own errors, and then if any have a dependency on another, they should make sure they dont crash as a result of an error occuring in that dependency.

Arguably, the most important would be the program handling its own error since it may be used within other programs also.

---

Your main method shouldn't need to worry about what happened to make the final program crash ("sub sub method"), it only needs to know why the sub method crashed. If it *does* matter for some reason, then the reasoning why the final program crashed is probably down to different parameters to what you passed in to begin with. The final program will say it crashed because of **X**, middle program should note this, find it is because of parameter **Y** from the first program and only report that back to the first program (as required).

You need to avoid creating a dependency between the final program and the first program as this will lead to a nightmare of maintenance as the final program is updated.

Comment: Can my main method catch the exception of the sub sub method?

Comment: It shouldn't have to, the submethod as you have described should already handle it, You only need to worry about your own direct dependencies, and their interaction inside your own program ("Look after #1")

Comment: How can you get the cause of the exception to your main method? Rethrowing it all the time or used in an inner exception? But what if you have three steps in hierarchy - how should this be managed?

Comment: @grabner - I've added an update to my answer in reply

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have different calls to a web service. Each call can fail, but the user should know why it failed (wrong username/password, missing permissions, ...). According to your description I would loose some of this information because you only get the response that the login couldn't be done. This dependency isn't good, but currently I don't know how to make it better.

Comment: @grabner - Its hard to give a specific answer, but your final program should tell the second program the reason it crashed, and then based on this information this second program needs to tell the first something about what happened. This *may* end up being the same message, but not always. You only need to concern yourself with your direct dependencies

Comment: You are right. If it's the same message, should I rethrow it? I want to be able to debug it to the deepest hierarchy.

Comment: @grabner - If it is the best way of portraying the information you require then yes, but above all, make sure you are only interested in the response from the middle program and not the final (which could be the same response).